# jquery .on() function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 fields Quantity, Rate, Total Amount. If any one keyup quantity or rate fields then amount show on Total Amount field. I have also an add button. If anyone click on add button then new row and delete link create dynamically. My problem is If I keyup quantity or rate fields then calculateSum() function work properly. suppose I create 2 row it's total amount 100+(100+100)=300. If i delete first one nothing change. If i delete last one then result show 200. but correct result is 100.Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here? Many thanks. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("keyup",".qty, .rate",function(){
        calculateSum();
    });

$(document).on("click",".del",function(){
        calculateSum();
    });
      });

function calculateSum() {
    var qty = [];
    $(".qty").each(function() {
            var num = parseFloat(this.value) || 1;
            qty.push(num);
    });

    var rate = [];
    $(".rate").each(function() {
            var num = parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
            rate.push(num);
    });
    var total = 0;
    $('input[name="total_amount[]"]').each(function(i){
        var amount = qty[i].toFixed(2)*rate[i].toFixed(2);
        total += amount;
        $(this).val(amount);
    });
    $("#sub_total").text(total);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
/*
This script is identical to the above JavaScript function.
*/
var ct = 1;

function new_link()
{
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;

    // link to delete extended form elements
    var delLink = '<div  style="text-align:right;margin-top:-20px"><a class="del" href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a></div>';

    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML + delLink;

    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);

}
// function to delete the newly added set of elements
function delIt(eleId)
{
    d = document;

    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);

    var parentEle = d.getElementById('newlink');

    parentEle.removeChild(ele);

}
</script>
        <style type="text/css">
table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px;
}


td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="newlink">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Rate</td>
                <td>Total Amount</td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
                 <td><input class='qty' type='text' name='qty[]'/></td>
                <td><input class='rate' type='text' name='rate[]'/></td>
               <td><input class='total_amount' type='text' name='total_amount[]'/></td>
            </tr>

                 </table>
    </div>
        <div id="sub_total">0</div>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="new_link()"/>

                <div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
                 <td><input class='qty' type='text' name='qty[]'/></td>
                <td><input class='rate' type='text' name='rate[]'/></td>
               <td><input class='total_amount' type='text' name='total_amount[]'/></td>
            </tr>
                 </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JQuery's `$` function is created to find elements. Why don't use it like in @Jubin's answar?

Comment: What do you mean the "calculateSum() function doesn’t work"? Is the function not executed or does the code break or calculate wrong?

Comment: why not call calculateSum() just at the end of delIt(eleId)? (as suggested by @MattWhipple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In **.ready()**:

```
$(document).on("click",".del", function() {
    // Call delIt before calculateSum() and get id from data attribute.
    delIt($(this).data("id")) 

    calculateSum();
});
```

in **new_link()**:

```
// link to delete extended form elements
var delLink = '<div style="text-align:right;margin-top:-20px"><a class="del" href="#" data-id=' + ct + '>Delete</a></div>';
// Set href = # and set ct to data-id instead.
```

Comment: your above code does not work. Thanks for your kind response. do you have any solution. please help me

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess your issue is that you have the logic for deletion in the href of the tag, but you're attaching the display update to the click event.  The click event will normally be fired *before* the link is followed, so the display is being updated before the deletion is done.  You should consolidate both of these into consistent unobtrusive JavaScript on the click event (add `ct` to the link dataset).  Then you could have a single event handler that dispatches to both functions, or have the delete function call the update function upon completion.

As a note that last sentence above should be a solution even with the existing code, but getting things closer to consistency/expected code wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes...exactly...the update is being called before the delete so it appears to be 1 behind.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
$(".qty, .rate").live("keyup",function(){
    calculateSum();
});
```

Comment: it's the delete part that doesn't work and any elements with class qty or rate added dynamically will not have the keyup handler attached if done this way

Comment: @Jubin Thomas <a class="del" href="javascript:delIt('+ ct +')">Delete</a> this link created dynamically if anyone click add button. Only quantity, rate keyup function work perfectly but Click function does not work. Thanks for your response

Comment: [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, it's going away, it won't be there much longer, it shouldn't be used. `.on()` is the correct replacement and works fine for delegated events as OP uses it. You are not even addressing the issue, the keyup works fine, it's click on `.del` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

here my 2 cent, i've rewrited the html using @Mario and @MattWhipple suggestion. i've also removed the unneeded extra elements at the end of your document using a string variable.

i don't think is the better way to do things, but for me is much clearer.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var templateText = '<div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">\
  <tr>\
    <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"/></td>\
    <td><input class="rate" type="text" name="rate[]"/></td>\
    <td><input class="total_amount" type="text" name="total_amount[]"/></td>\
  </tr>\
</table></div>';
      var ct = 1;

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("keyup", ".qty, .rate", calculateSum);
        $(document).on("click", ".del", delIt);
      });
      function calculateSum() {
        var total = 0;
        $('#newlink table').each(function(i, e) {
          var that = $(this);
          var qty = parseFloat(that.find('.qty').val()) || 1;
          var rate = parseFloat(that.find('.rate').val()) || 0;
          var amount = qty.toFixed(2)*rate.toFixed(2);
          that.find('.total_amount').val(amount);
          total += amount;
        });
        $("#sub_total").text(total);
      }
      function addRow() {
        ct++;
        var div1 = $(templateText);
        div1.attr('id', ct)
        var delLink = $('<div style="text-align:right;margin-top:-20px"> </div>').append($('<a class="del" href="#" >Delete</a>').data("id", ct));
        div1.append(delLink).appendTo('#newlink');
      }
      function delIt() {
        $('#' + $(this).data("id")).remove();
        calculateSum();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="newlink">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Rate</th>
          <th>Total Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input class='qty' type='text' name='qty[]'/></td>
          <td><input class='rate' type='text' name='rate[]'/></td>
          <td><input class='total_amount' type='text' name='total_amount[]'/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="sub_total">0</div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code also work perfectly. Thanks for your kind solution.

Answer (score -2):

use `.bind( eventType [, eventData], handler(eventObject) )`

Comment: The `.bind` method is only active for existing elements. So that won't work for new elements added dynamically (like the ones created in the `new_link()` method).

Comment: `bind` was deprecated and replaced with `on`

Comment: @rune [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) isn't deprecated, it's just no longer the 'preferred method'...

Comment: @nbrooks correct and since the jquery argument for deprecating is amongst other things "unpopular functionality" the difference really isn't that big :)